# Writing to the console using Task.Run() fails

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

A colleague of mine found an issue with our code and it took a while to hunt down exactly what was happening, but it can be best demonstrated by this simple example:

```
// Fails
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task.Run(() => Console.WriteLine("Hello World"));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

// Works fine
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write(String.Empty);
        Task.Run(() => Console.WriteLine("Hello World"));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

It’s clear from playing around with this that writing to the console anywhere from the main thread will allow the background thread to write to the console also, but we are struggling to understand why this is happening.  Can anyone explain what writing to the console from the main thread achieves that the first snippet does not?

Comment: You haven't described what happens in your failing case. On my box, it seems to hang until you hit return, at which point it prints.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes that is the behaviour I see

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have a suspicion as to what's going on. What I've observed:

- If you do *anything* with the console's output before starting the `ReadKey`, it's fine. This includes fetching `Console.Out` but not using it
- If you put a delay in so that the `Console.WriteLine` call *starts* before the `Console.ReadKey` call, it's fine (and you can have multiple `WriteLine` calls *while* `ReadKey` is waiting

I suspect that the first operation to use the console acquires a lock for initialization (to avoid it being initialized twice) and that the `ReadKey` method *keeps hold of the lock* until a key has been read. That would certainly explain every program I've run so far.

The operations which perform the hypothesized initialization are interesting though - reading `Console.Out` "fixes" the issue, but reading from `Console.In` doesn't.

I suspect that `ReadKey` initializes the output because the value is still echoed to the console... but I wouldn't like to swear to it.

Interestingly, using `Console.ReadLine()` instead of `Console.ReadKey()` doesn't cause the problem in the first place.

Comment: It certainly is interesting that `Console.ReadLine()` doesn't cause the same issue.  Thanks for taking the time

Answer (score 5):

Actually, the first case doesn't fail. "Hello World" appears just before the Application ends. This is a classical [Race Condition](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_Condition). In the first case,`Console.ReadKey()` from the main thread beats the task, and in the second case, the task wins. Unfortunately, I cannot tell you Exactly why writing the empty string makes the task win.

Comment: This is indeed the solution.

Comment: I don't think this is right. It's not that like the call to Console.WriteLine happens after the call to Console.ReadLine has *completed* - otherwise if you wait for a while, you'd see the output. It appears to be some sort of initialization problem, I think.

Comment: Or to be clearer - I believe it's a race condition, but only in terms of which call *starts* first, and only if `Console.ReadKey` is the first call to the console, neither of which are clear in the answer.