# C# reverseString method

Tags: c#, reverse

I am running the code below without any debug problems, but my results are off.

This is the code I have that is meant to reverse a string

```
{ namespace Code2040
  {
   public class ReverseString
     {
    public ReverseString ()
      {
        Task.Run (async () =>

            //helper function is the post function for the webrequest
            var helper = new Helper ();
            Session.Instance.SetToken (JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response> (
                await helper.Post ("http://challenge.code2040.org/api/getstring", 
                    JsonConvert.SerializeObject (new { token = "Y6C15DVN99" 
                         }))).Result);
            Console.ReadKey (true);
            //Reads out the line to verify if the token was printed out 
            Console.WriteLine (alorgorithmForReversingString.reverser (Session.Instance.Token));
            //Console.WrtieLine (alorgorithmForReversingString.reverser (Session.Instance.Token));
            Console.ReadLine ();
            Console.WriteLine ("hello");
        });
    }
}

//Algorithim for reversing the string
static class alorgorithmForReversingString
{
    public static string reverser (string tokenResult)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Debug");
        char[] arr = tokenResult.ToCharArray ();
        Array.Reverse (arr);
        return new string (arr);

    }

  }
```

}

To sum this code up I am getting a token value from a web post that I turn into a string value that is suppose to reverse the string. However when I compile the code it doesn't even return the debug console write line variable. Can anyone help.

Comment: Maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14384064/writing-to-the-console-using-task-run-fails

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem is that I had the Console.WriteLine() inside of the TaskAsync method. And I believe the TaskAsync method was only running the webpost and returning the results.

```
    public class ReverseString
{
    public ReverseString ()
    {

        Task.Run (async () => {

            //helper function is the post function for the webrequest
            var helper = new Helper ();
            Session.Instance.SetToken (JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response> (
                await helper.Post ("http://challenge.code2040.org/api/getstring", 
                    JsonConvert.SerializeObject (new { token = "Y6C15DVN99" 
                         }))).Result);
        });
        Console.WriteLine (alorgorithmForReversingString.reverser (Session.Instance.Token));
    }
}
```

}